# Runtime exception Android O with boot_completed

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to start an IntentService within my BOOT_COMPLETED receiver, but in Android O (API 26) I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Not allowed to start service Intent { act=intent.action.update cmp=packageName.services.OwnService }: 
app is in background
```

(Message is in one line, but this way it's easier readable)

How can I do this the correct way?

Comment: Aw, crap. I'll need to try to reproduce this. Assuming that your analysis is correct, your choices are to either make this a foreground service (use Android 8.0's `startForegroundService()` instead of `startService()`) or switch to scheduling a job with `JobScheduler`.

Comment: Aha! So I'm not the only one suddenly getting crashes on O because of this.

Comment: Yes, my solution was to start a JobScheduler (or JobIntentService). It works very well.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here are some options that I outlined in [a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/06/12/action_boot_completed-intentservice-android-8p0.html):

#### Workaround #1: startForegroundService()

Your `BroadcastReceiver` that receives the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast
could call `startForegroundService()` instead of `startService()` when on Android
8.0+:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;

public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i=new Intent(context, TestIntentService.class);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      context.startForegroundService(i);
    }
    else {
      context.startService(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this works, to an extent, even if your service does not actually
ever call `startForeground()`. You are given a window of time to get around
to calling `startForeground()`, "comparable to the ANR interval to do this".
If your work is longer than a millisecond but less than a few seconds,
you could skip the `Notification` and the `startForeground()` call. However,
you will get an error in LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.commonsware.myapplication, PID: 5991
 android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1775)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Of course, if you do not mind having a `Notification` briefly, you are welcome
to use `startForeground()` as Android expects you to, in which case you can
do background work normally, albeit with an entry showing up in the user's notification
shade.

#### Workaround #2: goAsync()

`BroadcastReceiver` has offered `goAsync()` since API Level 11. This allows your
receiver to do work off the main application thread, so you could get rid of the
`IntentService` entirely and move your code into the `BroadcastReceiver`.
You still only have the ANR
timeout period to work with, but you will not be tying up your main application
thread. This is better than the first workaround, insofar as it has the same
time limitation but avoids the nasty error. However, it does require some amount
of rework.

#### Workaround #3: JobScheduler

If your work will take more than a few seconds *and* you want to avoid the
`Notification`, you could modify your code to implement a `JobService` and
work with `JobScheduler`. This has the added advantage of only giving you
control when other criteria are met (e.g., there is a usable Internet
connection). However, not only does this require a rewrite, but `JobScheduler`
is only available on Android 5.0+, so if your `minSdkVersion` is less than 21,
you will need some other solution on the older devices.

**UPDATE**: Eugen Pechanec [pointed out `JobIntentService`](https://twitter.com/EPechanec/status/874347355058962433),
which is an interesting `JobService`/`IntentService` mashup.

Comment: Use the open source Firebase JobDispatcher might be an option for backward compatibility: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: @M66B: Yes, as might `JobIntentService` in the v26 support library -- see answer update.

Comment: Although JobIntentService is certainly interesting, it doesn't support job (work) conditions (like unmetered network available or device is charging). However, JobDispatcher can replace JobScheduler with minor code changes in most cases. At least I had success with it with minor effort.

Comment: I add that it's not needed if the app is ignoring battery optimizations, in that case it can call startService

Comment: The "goAsync" option work for about 10 seconds till it gets ANR, right ? It even says so in the docs : "As a general rule, broadcast receivers are allowed to run for up to 10 seconds" (here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync() ) . I think it should cover most cases.

Comment: Does using JobIntentService mean the job will try to work right away?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "I think it should cover most cases" -- that would depend on what work the `IntentService` did. "Does using JobIntentService mean the job will try to work right away?" -- it will be scheduled to run right away. However, at boot time, there is a fair bit of memory thrashing, because dozens of apps request this broadcast. The `JobIntentService` documentation indicates that the work may be delayed somewhat in these sorts of conditions.

Comment: @CommonsWare About JobIntentService , will it try to work right away in normal conditions (meaning not on boot) ?

Comment: FYI, the RemoteServiceException causes Android to display the app has stopped dialog on the pixel.

Comment: In my case, I start service as below: 
startForegroundService(new Intent(...)). from onStartCommand() of service class I am putting a notification and make this foreground service via startForeground(). 
Once task is done, I call stopService(). 
But in many cases I get a force code like below: 
Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
Based on some AOSP code analysis, i realised that force close is shown as showing Notification is not completed by framework.

Comment: // Check to see if the service had been started as foreground, but being
// brought down before actually showing a notification.  That is not allowed.
Message msg = mAm.mHandler.obtainMessage(                ActivityManagerService.SERVICE_FOREGROUND_CRASH_MSG);

Not sure how I can I make sure that before stop service call that notification is already posted. Any clue on this ?
Note: this happens only when some tasks get finished very quickly. In my case, most of the tasks works fine but only for super quick tasks this is happening

Comment: @vicky: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, as it is very difficult to follow what you have in your two comments.

Comment: Would schedule a WorkManager be another alternative? Using WorkManager seem much easy and straightforward.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: Probably, though I have not tried one from an `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver. Also, in general, I'm not sure how well this works from a receiver -- I don't know how they are handling ensuring that your work gets scheduled with `JobScheduler` when you are not in the foreground.

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background, when you receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` shouldn't your app be put on a whitelist, since it is handling a task like "Receiving a broadcast, such as an SMS/MMS message"?

Comment: @jpmcosta: I guess so, though I have not tried it personally.

Comment: Thanks for answer. As far as I can tell, that may vary with the device, as I'm having issues with some devices. I will have to test it further.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the following section of the Android O behaviour changes documentation https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#services

It now limits when the app is able to start background services.

Comment: Link is not working, can you update it please?