# How to detect process foreground for Android O

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

On our application there's a service that is normally started during `Application.OnCreate` (directly calling `context.startService`) and also later on via `AlarmManager` (refactor is in progress to migrate some of its work to JobScheduler).

Our application also have a `BroadcastReceiver` that gets launched with its direct intent.

Given the new limitations in Android Oreo (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) we're having an issue as follows:

- app/process is in background/dead
- BroadcastReceiver gets fired by the OS
- Application.onCreate() executes before the BroadcastReceiver
- Application.onCreate() code tries to run the Service

this leads to crash with "IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent".

I'm aware of the new recommended ways of launching a Service as answered by CommonsWare here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44505719/906362, but for this specific case, I simply want to have `if(process in foreground) { startService }`. I'm currently using the following method and it seems to work:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static boolean isProcessInForeground_V21(Context context) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = am.getAppTasks();
        return tasks.size() > 0;
    }
```

But I can't find the exact checks Android Oreo is doing (I got as far as here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java on the `startServiceCommon` method, but from there `requireForeground` flag seems to go to some native implementation)

So my question:

For the specific purpose of Android Oreo new limitations, how to check if my process is foreground before calling `startService`?

Comment: Perhaps you should not be starting a service in `onCreate()` of a custom `Application`. Start the service only when the service is needed. If your app is in the foreground, the service is useless.

Answer (score 0):

To continue your investigation: (TL;DR: see between horizontal lines at the bottom)

---

*Disclaimer, I don't know too much about Android internals, I just like digging in the source code.*
*Note: you can also navigate the code in Android Studio if you jump to file instead of class:*
[image]
*or searching for text in Project **and Libraries**.*
[image]

---

`IActivityManager` is defined by AIDL, that's why there are no sources for it:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IActivityManager.aidl#145

Based on [how AIDL needs to be implemented](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl#Implement) I found that `ActivityManagerService extends IActivityManager.Stub` (God bless Google indexing).

*Note I also found this, which might be an interesting read if you're really interested how things work internally.
https://programmer.group/android-9.0-source-app-startup-process.html*

[`ActivityManagerService` sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java) reveal that [in Oreo `startService` is forwarded to `ActiveServices`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#18146) which is located in the [same package](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActiveServices.java).

Assuming we're looking for an exception like this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {...}: app is in background uid UidRecord{af72e61 u0a229 CAC  bg:+3m52s273ms idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

we have to continue down the rabbit hole: [`requireForeground` gets assigned to `fgRequired` parameter and the message is here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActiveServices.java#385). The condition to allow this depends on the start mode returned by [`ActivityManagerService.getAppStartModeLocked(packageTargetSdk = 26 or greater, disabledOnly = false, forcedStandby = false)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#8432).

There are 4 start modes:

- APP_START_MODE_NORMAL (needs to be different than this, i.e. `!=`)
- APP_START_MODE_DELAYED (this is ok, i.e. `return null`)
- APP_START_MODE_DELAYED_RIGID
- APP_START_MODE_DISABLED

[Ephemeral apps](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/private/ephemeral_app.te) will immediately return `APP_START_MODE_DISABLED`, but assuming this is a normal app, we end up in [`appServicesRestrictedInBackgroundLocked`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#8400).
*Note: this is where some of the whitelist mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445436/253468 is decided.*
Since all branches but last return `APP_START_MODE_NORMAL`, this redirects to `appRestrictedInBackgroundLocked` where we find our [most likely suspect](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#8379):

```
    int appRestrictedInBackgroundLocked(int uid, String packageName, int packageTargetSdk) {
        // Apps that target O+ are always subject to background check
        if (packageTargetSdk >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            return ActivityManager.APP_START_MODE_DELAYED_RIGID;
        }
```

---

So the reason for denial is simply targeting O. I think the final answer to your question of how the OS decides if your app is foreground or background is [this condition in `getAppStartModeLocked`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#8438)

```
UidRecord uidRec = mActiveUids.get(uid);
if (uidRec == null || alwaysRestrict || uidRec.idle) {
```

My guess is that a missing record means it's not running (but then how is it starting a service?!), and `idle` means it's backgrounded. Notice that in my exception message the `UidRecord` is saying that it's idle and has been backgrounded for 3m52s.

I peeked into your `getAppTasks` and it's based on `TaskRecord.effectiveUid`, so I'm guessing that's quite close to listing `UidRecord`s for your app.

---

*Not sure if this helps, but I'll post it anyway, so if anyone wants to investigate more, they have more info.*