# Restarting service after reboot by using Broadcastreceiver is not working

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, reboot

I want to auto-start my service after device being rebooted as given on this website [Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-start-service-boot-example/).
Created BroadCastReceiverBootUpComplete class to restart the service(MyService.java) after reboot, but it is not starting at all.
I want MyService.java to run as soon as device get rebooted.
**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.shubham.servicedemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
    }
}
```

**BroadCastReceiverOnBootComplete.java**

```
package com.example.shubham.servicedemo;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BroadCastReceiverOnBootComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Intent serviceIntent  = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shubham.servicedemo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.shubham.servicedemo.BroadCastReceiverOnBootComplete"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting android version 26 above then you have to use startforeground service

```
 Intent mIntentForService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    mIntentForService.setAction(intent.getAction());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        context.startForegroundService(mIntentForService);
    else
        context.startService(mIntentForService);
```

check below link for more details

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502229/runtime-exception-android-o-with-boot-completed)

Note that this works, to an extent, even if your service does not actually
ever call `startForeground()`. You are given a window of time to get around
to calling `startForeground()`, "comparable to the ANR interval to do this".
If your work is longer than a millisecond but less than a few seconds,
you could skip the `Notification` and the `startForeground()` call.